# Toast is not shown while application is launching in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 application, and I've implemented a background agent which does some work and also updates my application's Tile and shows a toast notification to the user.

It works, except when I am launching the application (more specifically when control is in the `Application_Launching` event) in which case the Toast notification is not shown, but the Tile still gets updated. Has anyone ran into this before?

Comment: It is system behaviour. Toasts are not shown when the application is active.

Answer (score 0):

A toast will not be displayed if the current foreground application is the caller of the Show method. Toast notification only display in the running background agent or some of the work are finish.

Comment: Then, if I would like to show an alert message, what should I do?